# Do Spotfire's "min aggregation" and "marked by" correspond to any SQL statements?

Tags: sql, group-by, scatter-plot, spotfire

Say, I have a table with three columns and two rows:

```
x      y      my_type
---------------------
4      0      a
2      1      a
1      0      b
```

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish: in each of `my_type`, return *a* row with the minimal `x` coordinate.

The following SQL query

```
select min(x), y, my_type
from mydata
group by my_type
```

would give me this as a result:

```
x      y      my_type
---------------------
2      1      a
1      0      b
```

So I though that setting Spotfire's scatter plot axes to `min(x)` and `y`, and choosing `marked by my_type` would plot only this `a`-type point (2,1). But it plots both `a`-type points (4, 0) and (2, 1).

Two questions:

1. How do I make it plot only (2, 1)?
2. In general, do Spotfire's "min aggregation" and "marked by" correspond to any SQL statements?

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: @jarlh: I edited the question to add some context.

Comment: You say "_The following SQL query would give me this as a result:_". It shouldn't, because that query is invalid.

Comment: @jarlh: I tried it this code: 

    `SELECT min(Quantity), ProductID, OrderID`
    `FROM OrderDetails`
    `group by OrderID`

[here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all) and it worked. And my code in the question seems to be analogous. Could you please clarify why it's invalid?

Comment: you do not have `y` in `group by` but you do have it in `select` which is not allowed in most DBMS and in the remaining ones (like in MySQL) you get a random result.

Comment: @RadimBača: I see now. But as I said, I need to return "_a_ row with the minimal x" (not _the_ row, such that...). So I'm okay with a random result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spotfire is not good at managing your data; in fact it's pretty terrible at it. Spotfire instead generally expects you to have the data set figured out before it starts to visualize. one of the other answers above may help you with that on the database level.

assuming you're using an Information Link, you can of course modify the SQL statement powering said link in accordance with one of the answers, and that can be a solution.

in short: if your data set has 3 rows, 3 rows will be represented in the visualization unless some of those rows have been explicitly filtered out.

but to answer your questions:

**How do I make it plot only (2, 1)?**

you will need to either remove the other values you do not wish to plot from the data set, OR filter out those specific values using one of the various filtering mechanisms in the application (Filters Panel, Data Limiting Expression, etc.).

**In general, do Spotfire's "min aggregation" and "marked by" correspond to any SQL statements?**

I refer you to the [**Marker By** documentation from the Spotfire manual](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/html/scat/scat_properties_marker_by.htm):

> If you select (Row Number) here, then each row in the data table will be displayed as a separate marker in the visualization, even if several markers have identical values for the X-axis and Y-axis, and therefore are located at the exact same coordinates. These markers will be drawn on top of each other.
>
> You can, however, select to combine markers (known as aggregation) so that each marker shows for example the sum of all rows that have something in common.

**Marker By** is a visualization dimension, similar to **X Axis** or **Color By**. it has no similar function or statement in any SQL language as it's not in the same wheelhouse (or wheel..city even).

the `Min()` aggregation however should function exactly as you'd expect it to in SQL, i.e., it will return the minimum value contained in the column.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the following query

```
select *
from mydata m
where m.x = 
  (
    select min(x) min_x
    from mydata
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TestTable AS TABLE (
    X INT,
    Y INT,
    my_type NVARCHAR(2)
)

INSERT INTO @TestTable
VALUES
     (4, 0, 'a')
    ,(2, 1, 'a')
    ,(1, 0, 'b')

;WITH MinimumXGroupedByType
AS
(
    SELECT 
        MIN(X) AS min_x
        ,my_type
    FROM @TestTable
    GROUP BY my_type
)

SELECT T.* FROM @TestTable AS T
    INNER JOIN MinimumXGroupedByType AS M ON [M].[my_type] = T.[my_type] AND [M].[min_x] = T.[X]
```